# What is the limit of $\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{n}}{n^2\sqrt{n}}}$ as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do we calculate $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left(\sqrt {\frac{{1 + \sqrt n }}{{{n^2}\sqrt n }}}  + \sqrt {\frac{{\sqrt 2  + \sqrt n }}{{{n^2}\sqrt n }}}  +  \cdots  + \sqrt {\frac{2}{{{n^2}}}} \right)$$?

Comment: In each term, put common factor sqrt(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: your general term is

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{n}}{n^2\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}+1}$$

Now think of Riemann sums.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

They are the Riemann sums for the integral of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}$ in the interval $[0,1]$ with the uniform partition.